# Stop Page redirection on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've looked up a lot of tutorials and poked around on here but haven't found anything that addresses my specific issue.  I am guessing I have a syntax error or logic error somewhere in my code.  My issue is that whenever I submit the form, I get directed to the test.php page.  The php is working correctly as it is returning the correct result but I just want that to run and display the submitted form information underneath.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Computer swap form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "test.php" id="computerForm">
Serial Number: <br>
<input name="serialnumber" type="text">

<button id = "sub"> Submit </button>
</form>
<!--display the response returned after form submit -->
<span id ="result"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="script/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$sn = $_POST['serialnumber'];

if(!isset($sn))
{
    echo "error serial number not set";
}
else {
    echo "$sn successfully saved";
}
?>
```

my_script.js

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#computerForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#computerForm").serialize(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
});

$("#computerForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve what you require put all your logic in the `submit` handler, and call `preventDefault()` on the event argument provided to the handler function:

```
$("#computerForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(info) {
    $("#result").html(info);
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I was planning!  Thanks Rory!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped